# Excel: Shortcut key to move selection to specific row

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, openoffice

I am creating a bot where I need to move the selection (cursor) to a specific row, like row 1, or row 5. Does such shortcut feature exist or is it possible to create it?

Alternatively, does OpenOffice have this feature?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a few more details about how you are going about creating this bot? Maybe that will help find other options to accomplish what you are trying.

Comment: @CharlieRB The process of the bot is completely irrelevant to the question at hand. If there is a shortcut key, I will simply input this key within the bot, detailing the rest of the bot code will not be beneficial.

Comment: Was just trying to help. Below may be all you get.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and give the cell number you need

E.g., press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> then enter A450 (cursor will move to that cell)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, <kbd>CNTRL</kbd>+g will allow you to select any cell in any row.

Comment: How does it actually work? How do you add a cell number etc? The dialogue box that appears is quite odd.

Comment: Additionally, it should be noted that in dialog box you can use row or column notation to select an entire row (or column) rather than just a single cell i.e. enter 12:12 to select all of row 12, or b:b to select column B.  I'm not sure I understand the OP's questions in the comment above.

Comment: @Chenmunka The question was:  *"Does such shortcut feature exist..."* this question can be answered with a simple *Yes* . I just elaborated.